# Find and delete (strip) all occurances of html tag and its contents in visual studio code

Tags: html, parsing, visual-studio-code

How can I find and delete all occurrences of an html tag using Visual Studio Code.

As an example, I am trying to parse a page that is riddled with SVG tags.  I don't want the tags, nor the contents of those tags in the file.

Comment: You can use a regex like this: `<svg .+?>.+?</svg>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the "Find and Replace" popup in VS-Code (Windows: `CTRL + H`, Mac `⌥ + ⌘ + F`), then inside the "Search" input field there are three icons on the right side.

Press the right one `.*` in order to activate regular expressions.

After it's activated you can search for SVG tags like so:
`<\s*svg[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*svg>`

Leave the replace input empty and press enter in order to replace it with "nothing" and therefore removing the HTML-Tag and it's inner text.

But be careful, this will really delete **everything** between those matched tags.
So for example if you are looking for `<a>` tags, even this String will be completely removed: `<a href="/some-page">Some <span>special</span> formatted link</a>`

You can find an example with it here: https://regex101.com/r/ewEttF/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex Search and Emmet.

1. Use regex search to find the start tags: `<svg[^>]*>`
2. While the focus is still in the find dialog: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. this will select all matching cases and put focus on the editor
4. Move cursors after the opening tag: <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>
5. Use `Emmet: Balance outward` to select content of tag
6. Use `Emmet: Balance outward` to select content and tag start and tag end
7. Delete selected stuff with: <kbd>Delete</kbd>
8. End Multi Cursor with: <kbd>Esc</kbd>